# Implement Timeout in Node JS using Websockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

Following task is to be implemented in Node JS.
 Exposes a GET API as 
`"api/request?connId=19&timeout=80"`

This API will keep the request running for provided time on the server side. After the successful completion of the provided time it should return `{"status":"ok"}`

Implement the above by building a socket server accepting HTTP requests.

I am confused whether to use `Socket.io` means Httpserver or `net.createServer()`. How socket.io can be used with express routes as I have no client(frontend) to trigger the event for emit  on api hit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I don't think socket here means websockets so no socketio needed. So create simple express app with `app.get('/api/request',...` and use timeout to respond with `res.json({status:"OK"});`

Comment: hii,alok do u have any solution for this problem now.